# XcodeでCorePlotのヘッダーファイルが読み込めない

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

どうしてもわからないので教えて下さい。
CorePlotのグラフを使いたくて導入しようとしています。

1.podfileの作成
2.pod install
3.フォルダ内のxcwrokspaceを開く

上記の手順でcoreplotをCocoaPodsでインストールしたのですが、
ViewController.hでimportしようとしても
フォルダ（CorePlot）までの階層しか出てきません
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ファイル自体はCorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.hの階層に存在します
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

LINKをみても特に問題ないように見えるのですが、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

理由がわかる方がいたらお願いします。

Comment: `#import <CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h>`では？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り#import <CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h>なんですが、xcodeの機能で出てこないんです。手打ちで入れてもエラーが出ます。

Comment: podfileの内容がおかしかったようです。解決できました。ありがとうございます。